# How to fix Provider configuration not present error in Terraform plan

Tags: terraform

I have moved Terraform configuration from one Git repo to other.

Then I ran Terraform init and it completed successfully.

When I run Terraform plan, I find below issue.

```
Terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Provider configuration not present
│
│ To work with data.aws_acm_certificate.cloudfront_wildcard_product_env_certificate its original provider
│ configuration at provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].cloudfront-acm-us-east-1 is required, but it
│ has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration is removed while objects created by that provider
│ still exist in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
│ data.aws_acm_certificate.cloudfront_wildcard_product_env_certificate, after which you can remove the provider
│ configuration again.
```

The data resource looks like this,

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "cloudfront_wildcard_product_env_certificate" {
  provider = aws.cloudfront-acm-us-east-1
  domain   = "*.${var.product}.${var.environment}.xyz.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
}
```

After further research I found that by removing below line, it works as expected.

```
provider = aws.cloudfront-acm-us-east-1
```

Not sure what is the reason.

Comment: So remove it if "it works as expected." without it. Why do you want to use something that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you were using a multi-provider configuration in the former repo. I.e. you were probably using one provider block like

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "some-region"
  access_key = "..."
  secret_key = "..."
}
```

and a second like

```
provider "aws" {
  alias      = "cloudfront-acm-us-east-1"
  region     = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "..."
  secret_key = "..."
}
```

Such a setup can be used if you need to create or access resources in multiple regions or multiple accounts.

Terraform will use the first provider by  default to create resources (or to lookup in case of data sources) if there is no provider specified in the resource block or data source block.

With the `provider` argument in

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "cloudfront_wildcard_product_env_certificate" {
  provider = aws.cloudfront-acm-us-east-1
  domain   = "*.${var.product}.${var.environment}.xyz.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
}
```

you tell Terraform to use a specific provider.

I assume you did not move the second provider config to the new repo, but you still tell Terraform to use a specific provider which is not there. By removing the `provider` argument, Terraform will use the default provider for `aws`.

##### Further possible reason for this error message

Just for completeness:
The same error message can appear also in a slightly different setting, where you have a multi-provider config with resources created via the second provider. If you now remove the resource config of these resources from the Terraform config and at the same time remove the specific provider config, then Terraform will not be able to destroy the resources via the specific provider and thus show the error message like in your post.

Literally, the error message indicates this second setting, but it does not fit exactly to your problem description.